# Using Pi as a web server locally - how to set up pages after nginx install?

Tags: networking, web-server, nginx

I have just followed the [Setting up an NGINX web server on a Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/nginx.md) tutorial on the RPi Site.

Now, I'm going to follow a tutorial on setting up say a Django webpage.  What I'm not clear on and need to connect, is where/how do I now set up a custom web page that's accessible via the NGINX Server?

Overall, I just want to visit (say) `192.168.0.1` (or whatever my Pi's IP is) on a local network and have my custom webpage show up.

Then, later on, I might design *another* web page that does something totally different, so would like to "swap out" the site info so visiting the my RPi's IP goes to that *new* page.

Answer (score 1):

> Overall, I just want to visit (say) `192.168.0.1` (or whatever my Pi's
>   IP is) on a local network and have my custom webpage show up.

If you didn't change any config file of Nginx (I mean `root` section of `/etc/nginx/sites-available`), you can put your `.html` file into this location:

```
/var/www/html
```

---

In addition, read [this simple documentation](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#configure-nginx-for-your-site) to configure the Nginx service.